# POST input field value to factory to REST backend without polluting global space

Tags: angularjs

in Angularjs, i'm trying to grab value entered by user into an input field, to POST it to my REST backend.

Here is the factory:

```
myfac.factory('prosFactory', ['$http', function ($http) {
    var baseUrl = 'https://api.parse.com/1/classes/Buddies';
    var parseCredentials = {headers: { 'X-Parse-Application-Id':'xxx', 'X-Parse-REST-API-Key':'yyy', 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}};
    return {
        postPros: function () {
            return $http.post(baseUrl, {"firstName":myInput, parseCredentials);
        }
    }
}
]);
```

Here is the controller:

```
function AddProcontroller($scope, prosFactory) {
    $scope.addPros = function() {
                myInput = $scope.firstName; // pollutes global namespace

        prosFactory.postPros()
            .success(function(data, status) {
                alert("added !!"); 
            }).error(function(data, status) {
                alert("error");
            }
        );
    }
}
```

Here is html:

```
<form name="addProForm" ng-controller="AddProcontroller">
    <div> First Name: <input name="firstName" ng-model="firstName"></div>
    <button type="button" ng-click="addPros()">Add entry</button>

</form>
```

The system works correctly, you can see that "myInput" is a variable that grabs field content and pass it above in the factory. Problem is that myInput is in the global namespace, and this system is not really "angularJs" way. Could you please tell me how to improve the code so I can pass values grabbed from input field, to the factory without polluting global namespace ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass it as an argument:

```
postPros: function (myInput) {
    return $http.post(baseUrl, {"firstName":myInput}, parseCredentials);
}

$scope.addPros = function() {
    prosFactory.postPros($scope.firstName)
        .success(function(data, status) {
            alert("added !!"); 
        }).error(function(data, status) {
            alert("error");
        }
    );
};
```